# Can't boot the Linux - Kernel panic - not syncing - Any help appreciated

Tags: linux, debian, boot, linux-kernel, kali-linux

Info: I have Kali on dual boot with windows, and the Kali partition is encrypted (you can see in the terminal "please unlock crypto...").

I had some issues with a package called libc6, while installing my laptop software for controlling the brightness, and rgb, and other things on my asus laptop... so after troubleshooting that I found that I should apt --fix-broken to fix the package that was installed incorrectly.

So I did. Meanwhile the --fix-broken thingie, had it's own issues that after completing made me not able to run anything. I couldn't re-run the terminal, or anything really.

So i thought maybe reboot will fix it. Which lead to this screen you see here: [image: Kernel panic mode]

If you can't see the image here is what it looks like:

```
Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done.
Not activating Mandatory Access Control as /sbin/tomoyo-init does not exist.
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100
CPU: 7 PID: 1 Comm: run-init Tainted: G       E       5.10.0-kali7-amd6 #1 Debian 5.10.28-1kali1
Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG Strix G531GU_G531GU, BIOS G531GU.309 04/29/2020
Call Trace:
dump_stack+0x6b/0x83
do_exit.cold+0xb3/0xb3
do_group_exit+0x33/0xa0
__x64_sys_exit_group+0x14/0x20
do_syscall_64+0x33/0x80
entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
RIP: 0033:0x7f4f2f200699
Code: 00 4c 8b ...
RSP: 002b: 00007ffc56e73ffB EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000e7
```

So now I got no idea how to boot it. I got no idea how to access it from like liveCD to change some stuffs as per other threads I found on internet, since the HDD is encrypted.

Was wondering, is there any tool or USB image that can run on the boot, that will at least give me access to the terminal? I know it's kinda dumb since imo the kernel is not even running properly, but I just want to avoid re-installing everything from scratch, because it was highly customized and full of data Linux.

More info: The package that the software required was 3.2 of glibc6 and my Linux had 3.1 installed, so I download deb package and installed it like every other with dkpg -i. I thought what's the worst that can happen... and it did :D *

Comment: The package `libc6` is most likely the C standard library, which is essentially the fundamental basic library that is used by basically every program on the system. Any problems related to updating it are going to be bad news. Downloading random `deb` packages without checking first if they are intended for the specific version of the Linux distribution you're using is **a very bad idea**. A liveCD can certainly be used to access your data, but you must now learn the basics you tried to skip over.

Comment: Thanks for the input @telcoM . Will defo consider it in the future wrong moves I am about to make :D Yeah, I should have done a better research on what glibc is, and what is the purpose of it, but I didn't, and now I ended up in trouble.
I am trying to learn as I go with Linux, I haven't had any course, or extensive experience with linux administration, just basic stuffs.
Thanks again for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get yourself some liveCD or other bootable Linux media, and boot the system from it.

First lesson: **Don't blindly trust any random stranger on the internet.** If some tutorial or discussion thread suggests that you should run some command, make sure you understand what it's going to do before you actually run it.

The first step in accessing an encrypted Linux volume in a recovery context is most likely going to be a `cryptsetup` command. In this case, your picture indicates the password prompt was:

```
Please unlock disk nvme0n1p6_crypt:
```

This tells me the encrypted volume is on the 6th partition of the first NVMe storage device on the system (and the 1st and probably only namespace on it). This gives us the device name: `/dev/nvme0n1p6`, and the default name of the encrypted volume `nvme0n1p6_crypt`.

Assuming that your highly customized system uses the most common LUKS encryption, the command to unlock the encryption manually would then be:

```
cryptsetup open /dev/nvme0n1p6 nvme0n1p6_crypt --type luks
```

But wait! Don't just blindly run this command. Run `man cryptsetup` first, and see if the command I suggested above seems correct and makes sense to you. (Remember the first lesson.)

This should create a `/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p6_crypt` device, which will allow you (and the liveCD system) to access the contents of the encrypted volume in plaintext, until the volume is closed or the system is rebooted.

In your picture, the command executed by the boot process to check your Kali root filesystem seems to be something like `fsck.ext4 -a -C0 /dev/mapper/crypto_kali-root`. This tells me the installation used an *encrypted LVM* set-up: the standard form of LVM logical volume device names is `/dev/mapper/<volume group name>-<logical volume name>`. There's also an alternative (legacy, but still widely used) naming scheme: it would be `/dev/<volume group name>/<logical volume name>`.

Before you can mount the filesystem, you must make sure the LVM volume group (consisting of just the one LVM "physical volume": the encrypted volume we're trying to recover) is activated and the logical volume device is available.

LVM has quite a few commands, all beginning with letters `pv`, `vg` or `lv`. Sometimes they are all packaged into a single binary, named `lvm` to save space. This can happen in initramfs environments or with some liveCDs. If this is the case, just prefix the actual LVM command with the word `lvm`, e.g. instead of just `vgscan`, run `lvm vgscan`.

First, you should run `vgscan`. It tells the LVM to re-scan the available disks and partitions for LVM content. On modern distributions, `udev` rules will usually trigger this automatically whenever new disk-like devices appear (e.g. when unlocking an encrypted disk), but in a recovery scenario like this, it does not hurt to be explicit. If there are any problems with the LVM metadata, the `vgscan` command will display warnings or errors, so this is also a good basic LVM health check.

From the `fsck.ext4` command in your picture, we know the name of the Kali LVM volume group (`crypto_kali`) and the name of one logical volume (`root`). If we didn't know those, `vgscan` should have told us the name of the volume group: `Found volume group "crypto_kali" using metadata type lvm2` or something similar. To see the names of individual logical volumes within the volume group, you can use the `lvs` command, or `lvdisplay` for a more verbose listing.

Before LVM logical volumes can be accessed, they must be activated. This may or may not happen automatically as LVM devices are detected; again, an explicit manual activation command does not hurt and gives us a chance to see the error messages if there is a problem with the activation. You can activate all the logical volumes in the volume group at once, with `vgchange -ay crypto_kali`. If you run `lvs`, the `Attr` field will show a letter `a` in the 5th position whenever a logical volume is active.

Now you are ready to mount your Kali root filesystem:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/kali
mount /dev/mapper/crypto_kali-root /mnt/kali
```

If your Kali environment included other logical volumes, you can mount them also in the same way. At this point, you can recover and backup all your customizations and data, and I would urge you to do so.

Fixing a system with a broken or overwritten `glibc6` is possible, but somewhat tedious and will require finding out the correct version of `glibc` that should be there. You would need to manually remove or move aside the broken/wrong library files and place the correct ones in the right positions. With the skill level you've demonstrated so far, reinstalling and then restoring the data you recovered and backed up might be easier.

Also, did you notice how I pulled some important facts out of small details in your attached screenshot? If you are going to learn hacking (as evidenced by the fact you're using Kali in the first place), then **you'll need to develop that kind of eye for details**, along with the necessary understanding of system fundamentals to make effective use of what you can discover.

Comment: Woah man, you deserve a medal!
I don't know if this is the solution that I need, but I will try all this first thing in the morning!
Yeah re-installing is not very optimal, but I guess it's the only choice I have here, before learn some more under-the-hood Linux fundamentals.
I started out of recently using Kali, and indeed I am slowly getting into learning the Linux first and then going into more hacky stuff.
Your input has provided insane value for me, and I am grateful for that.
Thank you!

Comment: Yep, this was the solution for me. After this experience, I have re-installed everything, restored the data and installed Timeshift (a program for backup / restore).
I understand that lack of knowledge exist for me for the Linux under-the-hood fundamentals, so in case this repeats, i have snapshots of all the things I have set-up, to not re-install everything next time this happens.
Cheers again telcoM!